# Problems with jQuery cookie plugin (cookie expire doesn't work)

Tags: jquery, plugins, cookies

I've a grueling problem with the jQuery cookie plugin. The expire option don't work at all my computer & browsers.

It's just the following line:

```
$.cookie( 'basket_id' , basket_id , { expires: 365 , path: '/' });
```

basket_id is a string.

According to this code, a cookie should be set and expire after one year.

The cookie is set (I see it @ firebug), but become's deleted after reloading the website (F5).

I have absolutly no idea about this issue?!

Does anyone can help me? I don't know anymore where I have to look...

greez
Chris

(and of course, the plugin is properly included)

*edit* and the expiration date shown at firebug is correct too (+365 days)

Comment: Check your browser settings ... maybe you delete cookies on browser shutdown? Tools/Options/Privacy/History/Keep Until should be "they expire"

Comment: Hey sorry, maybe my presentation of the problem was a bit inaccurate, but I didn't shut down / restart the browser, i've just refreshed the website by hitting F5.  "Tools/Options/Privacy/History/Keep Until should be "they expire" yes, my browser uses this setting

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete bins that how can you use cookie plugin and read and reset cookie.
On this demo, just click on each element it will store text/value of that element in cookie then click on read cookie button to check stored cookie value.

**Demo** http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp7i

Comment: thank you! But I think I've the absolutly same 'syntax' like your example:         // Set Cookie
        $.cookie('lastClicked', ckVal, {
            expires: 2,
            path: "/"
        });

Comment: Ok thank you, I've just copied your example to my code and it works (only the cookie name was different). Their is obviously some other code somewhere which is deleting the cookie!

Comment: make sure that your cookie path is correct and has correct read and write permissions applied on it. Also check you browser privacy settings for e.g., if Mozilla Firefox then Tools->options->Privacy Tab check in History section drop down option "Use Custom Settings For History"